# Why doesn't this code also return False when it returns True?

Tags: python, boolean, return-value

The `return true` statement is executed only when the `if` statement is true, but shouldn't the code return `False` too, irrespective of the `if` statement because it is out of indentation? I don't understand how this works...

```
def booll(x):
    if x == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: If the input `x` happens to be zero, the `if` statement will execute and return `True`.  Once the function returns from that point, nothing following it will execute.

Comment: That  is how function works, it already returned the function with true. after return then the execution in the function stops. it wont go to the next statement

Comment: "but shouldn't the code return "False" too irrespective of "If-statement" as it is out of indentation??" no, not at all. It should only `return False` if the `if` statement evaluates to False, and the body of the if statement is never executed, because if it is executed, *it will `return True`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when output is returned by the function , the method is popped out of call stack hence no further executuin happens

Answer (score 2):

When a `return` statement is reached, the execution of the function is ended.

Answer (score 0):

The function will *only* return once, in either 1 of the scenarios:

- If the `if` statement is satisfied, it returns `True` and the
  function ends.
- If the `if` statement is *not* satisfied, it will run to the end of
  the function and return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call return, it **stops** a function and exits with the value provided to `return`.

For example,

```py
def return_example():
    print("This runs")
    return 0
    print("This doesn't run")
```

In the example, the function prints "this runs", and then exits with the value 0. In your example, `booll` returns `True` if `x == 0`. If `x == 0`, then `booll` **exits** with `True`. If `x` isn't `0`, then it returns `False`. The `return True` doesn't run.

Answer (score -1):

In your code , the phrase `return False` will be executed every time you call the code if your `if` conditional is false.

and `return False` totally independent of  `if` statement. and the function execution stops when the first `return statement` is reached.

Your given code is similar to the code of `if else` block.

```
def booll(x):
    if x == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

make sure that indentation is correct otherwise you will run to error.
I am not clearly getting what logic you are trying to execute. Can you please explain a bit more about it.

Comment: yes, i can add the else statement. what i was confused about why it doesn't return "False" statement when its outside the "if" statement indentation. I am not trying to accomplish anything, just wanted to know how the flow works. Now i understand that the function stops executing after return....

Comment: The thing is that the python compiler executes the block of function untill it first encounters the `return statement` or last line of function block (if return statement is not there). Since in your case the compiler gets the first `return` in side `if ` block when you are passing `booll(0)` , after that code block execution stops and the value is returned. A function can't have multiple `return` within same scope and same condition. if you want multiple parameter as return use something like list , dictionary(json formatting),tuples etc.

Answer (score -2):

Well, a function execution ends when it *returns* a value. So, when the function has returned `True`, its execution has stopped, and thus, it does not go to the next line.
If you want the function to 'return' multiple times, you can use the `yield` keyword, in this way:

```
def booll(x):
    if x == 0:
        yield True
    yield False
```

Comment: Ah!  great I got it now...Thanks:)

Comment: No, this is absolutely not how `yield` works. The `booll` function *returns neither `True` nor `False`*. Rather, it returns a generator object

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, apologies for posting wrongly. Now I have edited the answer. Thanks